# access to a text file and get the content with MATLAB command

Tags: matlab

is there a matlab function that read the content of txt files and return the content or each line ?
I've tried

```
xmld read
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [Googling](http://goo.gl/D3kuqH) that first? There are virtually a myriad of questions and answers on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this topic

[Read a whole text file into a MATLAB variable at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537520/read-a-whole-text-file-into-a-matlab-variable-at-once)

Matlab has several functions for reading a text file

1. Read the whole file : [fileread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html)
2. Read line by line: [fopen](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) + [fgetl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) + fclose